# Access Solution Configurations via Roslyn API?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, roslyn

Is there any way to access the [Solution Configurations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/25/solution-configurations.aspx) using the Roslyn API? I installed the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces) 0.7.4052301-beta, but couldn't find a way to get or manipulate Solution Configurations.

```
let f = @"C:\dir\to\file.sln"
let sln = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync f |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Solutions Configurations may be more of a Visual Studio concept, so I took a look at [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices), but couldn't find anything either.

Comment: Use `EnvDTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations` and wrap everything with try-catches because it's a [terrible interface](http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2008/08/29/the-convoluted-build-configuration-of-the-automation-model-envdte-envdte80.aspx). Internally, the build system doesn't care about the solution and project configurations/platforms, because it's got a separate set of properties for each combination -- it's just told to build one of them (the active configuration) per project.

Comment: Why do you need them, by the way? What are you trying to do?

Comment: My immediate need is to remove all other configurations besides "Release" and "Debug" from the .sln and .csproj files. There is roughly 100 solutions to check and many have 8 configurations based on environments that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get solution configuration information from the Roslyn API, we don't really concern ourselves about that thing. The MSBuild API itself added as part of Visual Studio "14" an API to *read* MSBuild solution files, but there's still no API to write. Cameron's suggestion of using EnvDTE might be your best approach (where "best" in this case means "your only option, despite it being a terrible API.")

Comment: Do you have any more details on the MSBuild API for 14? I just uninstalled CTP 4 yesterday.

Comment: There's now a Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile API that you can call. We use it in Roslyn: http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Workspaces/Core/Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs